# MySQL - Rows to columns with strings

Tags: mysql, sql

I've read this answer here, [MySQL - Rows to Columns](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9668036/804928), and I've been able to apply it for my situation up until the aggregate function (**Step 3**).

I'm trying to convert the rows in `itemname` to columns for the rows in `itemvalue` in the following **table**:

| hostid | itemname | itemvalue |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | address | 12 street |
| 2 | email | so@gmail |
| 3 | name | legend |

I applied the following code:

```
create view table_extended as (
  select
    history.*,
    case when itemname = "address" then itemvalue end as address,
    case when itemname = "email" then itemvalue end as email,
    case when itemname = "name" then itemvalue end as name
  from history
);
```

And now I have the **table_extended**:

| hostid | itemname | itemvalue | address | email | name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | address | 12 street | 12 street | NULL | NULL |
| 1 | email | so@gmail | NULL | so@gmail | NULL |
| 1 | name | legend | NULL | NULL | legend |

In **step 3** he uses `sum` to aggregate the extended table which all of the values are integers. I tried creating another view, with the following code, but of course these are strings so it turned all of rows except for hostid to 0.

```
create view history_itemvalue_pivot as (
  select
    hostid,
    sum(address) as address,
    sum(email) as email,
    sum(name) as name
  from history_extended
  group by hostid
);
```

It looked like this:

| hostid | address | email | name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |

How can I consolidate all of the  rows with `NULL` in order to get the following:

| hostid | address | email | name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 12 street | so@gmail | legend |

Comment: To the string columns use MAX instead of SUM!

Comment: ^^ Yes, because `MAX()` will compare them by collation and will exclude the NULLs from the result set to collapse down to a single row. Otherwise, looks good.

Comment: @JorgeCampos in my statement `case when itemname = "address" then itemvalue end as address,` do you know how I could assign `n/a` if `address` row is empty?

Comment: @inspired you can use the [IFNULL Function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`GROUP_CONCAT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html#function_group-concat) string function. This function tries to concatenate the strings matched on the `GROUP BY` clause and when encounters a `NULL` value, it just ignores it.

```
SELECT hostid,
       GROUP_CONCAT(address)    AS address,
       GROUP_CONCAT(email)  AS email,
       GROUP_CONCAT(name)       AS name
FROM (SELECT history.*,
             CASE WHEN itemname = "address" THEN itemvalue END AS address,
             CASE WHEN itemname = "email" THEN itemvalue END AS email,
             CASE WHEN itemname = "name" THEN itemvalue END AS name
      FROM history
) history_extended
GROUP BY hostid
```

Check the demo [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/36M5CkwjWrzpdAc6qxyVx9/0).

Note: I've noticed that in your first reference of the table you have three different host ids while in the following one you're referencing only one host id. Are there some typos?